# solr replication: what are 'master (searching)' and 'master (replicable)' fields

Tags: solr, lucene

I see `master (searching)` and `master (replicable)` fields on `host/solr/#/core_1/replication` page and wondering how does it impact me given that I don't have any master/slave replication.

If I don't have any replicas, does it make any impact on performance by enabling or disabling replication?

Also, when i am indexing new documents, I see `master (searching)` size growing even when I disable the replication from this UI. What does it imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically nothing. The replication request handler has been set as implicitly defined since Solr (if I remember well) 5, so that's basically the reason why that section is enabled.

The replication handler is doing a kind of versioning of the index (for enabling replication procedures) so

- if you are on a standalone instance I don't think it has some performance impact
- if you are on master / slave scenarios then it is used for replicating the index
- if you are on SolrCloud the replication is used behind the scenes between nodes (e.g. for node recovery)

So in few words: don't worry about that :)

Comment: @MatsLindh actually some numbers are size, which grow when more files are indexed.